# Delete Row HTML

Tags: javascript, html

> I have created a Dynamic HTML table where the user can add/delete rows if they want to. There will be 2 rows to complete at one time. I want to delete the row but for my coding I only able to delete the first row, the second row cannot delete. Anyone have idea on how to delete the row?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#addrow').click(function () {
       addItem();
   });
   $(document).on('click', '.delete-row', function () {
       $(this).parents('.item-row').remove();
   });
});
    
function addItem() {
    var itemRow =
        '<tr class="item-row">' +
        '<td><a id="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">Delete</a></td>' +
        '<td><textarea class="form-control" id="desc" rows="1"></textarea></td>' +
        '<td><input class="form-control tx-right" type="text" id="qty" onkeyup="calc()" value="0"></td>' +
        '<td><input class="form-control tx-right" type="text" id="unitprice" value="0"></td>' +
        '<td><input class="form-control tx-right" type="text" id="amount" disabled></td>' +
        '</tr>'+
    '<tr class="item-row">' +
        '<td></td>' +
        '<td colspan="2"></td>' +
        '<td class="tx-right">Tax:</td>' +
            '<td><select class="form-control select2 input-sm" id="ddlTax">' + "<% =sTaxDDL %>" + '</select></td>' +
            '<td><input class="form-control tx-right" type="text" id="amounttax"></td>' 
    '</tr>';
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
 <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="wd-5p">Action</th>
          <th class="wd-25p">Description</th>
          <th class="wd-10p tx-right">Qty</th>
          <th class="wd-10p tx-right">Unit Price</th>
          <th class="wd-15p tx-right">Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="items_table">
        <tr class="item-row">
          <td><a id="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">Delete</a></td>
          <td><textarea class="form-control row-desc" id="desc" rows="1"></textarea></td>
          <td><input class="form-control tx-right row-qty" type="text" id="qty" onkeyup="calc()" value="0"></td>
          <td><input class="form-control tx-right row-unitprice" type="text" id="unitprice" value="0"></td>
          <td><input class="form-control tx-right row-amount" type="text" id="amount" disabled></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item-row">
          <td></td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
          <td class="tx-right">Tax:</td>
          <td><input class="form-control tx-right" type="text" id="amounttax"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="hiderow">
          <td colspan="5" class="tx-center tx-15"><b><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row"><i class="fe fe-plus-circle"></i>Add an Item</a></b></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
<!-- End Row -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,
add an onclick function **onclick = "deleteRow(this)"** into delete **a** tag

Second,
add a javascript function

```
function deleteRow(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  var next = row.parentNode.rows[ row.rowIndex + 0 ];
  row.parentNode.removeChild(next);
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the next row using [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
var row = $(this).closest('.item-row');
row.next().remove();
row.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.next()`

```
let row = $(this).parents('.item-row');

   row.next(".item-row").remove();
   row.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this function**

```
function removeTR(elem) {

    var row = $(elem).closest("TR");
    var name = $("TD", row).eq(0).html();

    //if (confirm("Do you want to delete: " + name)) {
    //    //Get the reference of the Table.

    var table = $("#items_table")[0];

    //Delete the Table row using it's Index.
    table.deleteRow(row[0].rowIndex);
    }
```